# Python egg creation ignores non .py files

Tags: python, egg

I would like to create an egg from two directories and want to include `.config` and `.log` files. The structure of the directories is the following:

```
MSKDataDownloader
|_______configs
        |________sensors.config


MSKSubscriber
|_______doc
        |________dependencies.log
```

Here's my `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
        name='MSKDataDownloader',
        version='1.0.0',
        description='Data Downloader',
        packages=find_packages(),
        include_package_data=True,
        package_data={
        'MSKDataDownloader': ['config/*.config'],
        'MSKSubscriber': ['doc/*.log']
        'MSKSubscriber': ['config/*.config']
        }
)
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it not including the `.config` and `.log` files in the egg.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `include_package_data=True` doesn't mean what you think it means (or what most reasonable people would think it means). The short version is, just get rid of it.

---

From [the docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords):

> If set to `True`, this tells `setuptools` to automatically include any data files it finds inside your package directories that are specified by your `MANIFEST.in` file. For more information, see the section below on [Including Data Files](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files).

If you follow the link, you'll see that it in fact makes `setuptools` ignore whatever you told it explicitly in `package_data`, and instead look for every file mentioned in `MANIFEST.in` and find it within your directory tree (or source control tree):

> If using the `setuptools`-specific `include_package_data` argument, files specified by `package_data` will not be automatically added to the manifest unless they are listed in the `MANIFEST.in` file.

And, since you don't have a `MANIFEST.in`, this means you end up with nothing.

So, you want to do one of two things:

- Remove `include_package_data=True`.
- Create a `MANIFEST.in` and remove `package_data=…`.

---

This is all complicated by the fact that there are lots of examples and blog posts and tutorials left over from the `distribute` days<sup>1</sup> that are just plain wrong for modern `setuptools`. In fact, there are a whole lot more out-of-date and wrong posts out there than correct ones.

The obvious answer is to just only use the tutorials and examples from the PyPA on pypa.org… but unfortunately, they haven't get written tutorials that cover anywhere near everything that you need.

So, often, you pretty much much have to read old tutorials, then look up everything they tell you in the reference docs to see which parts are wrong.

---

<sub>1. IIRC, in `distribute`, the `include_package_data=True` *would* cause your extra files to get added to an sdist, just not to anything else. Which still sounds useless, right? Except that you could make your egg and other distributions depend on building the sdist then running a script that generates the `MANIFEST.in` programmatically. Which was useful for… I forget, something to do with pulling version files from source control maybe?</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I missed one thing. Do you suggest that I copy the contents of the .config files to `MANIFEST.in` file? But my code is looking for `.config` file so how would this help? I am a little confused!

Comment: @Rohit No, if you go that route, you want to add the _files_, not their _contents_. But the simpler solution is to just not use `include_package_data=True`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but the .config and .log files are removed whenever I run the setup.py file. I guess there is no way to include .config files in an egg?

Comment: @Rohit There definitely is a way to include .config files in an egg. Without seeing a [mcve] of what you tried, I can't debug it. But, meanwhile, the usual way to handle config files is to treat them as `pkg_resources` and change your program to read them with [`resource_stream`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api). After all, how were you planning to read the config files at runtime once you get them into an egg archive? Unzip the egg on the fly?